# What would I have to add if I wanted to substitute blueberry juice for light cream in this pie recipe?

Tags: substitutions, pie, cream

I'm going to be making this pie recipe:
http://ediblejersey.com/editorial/summer-2011/ricotta-blueberry-pie/

I have a bag of frozen blueberries that are now blueberries in their own juice, would i be able to substitute the blue berry juice for the light cream 1:1 or should I add something else?

Thank you!

Comment: That's a rather drastic proposed substitution - might do better to start with a different recipe.

Comment: I'd be concerned that the blueberry juice could cause the filling to split or fail to set. I'd bake the pie per the recipe, topping with well-drained berries, and saving the juice. Thicken the juice by adding cornstarch or arrowroot and simmering. Cool a bit before spreading over your baked ricotta pie.